# Automatic date update in a cell when another cell's value changes (as calculated by a formula)

Tags: excel, vba, date, formula

I have a formula in C2, say `=A2+B2`. Whenever C2 changes value (actual value, not formula) I want to have the present date and time updated in D2.

I have tried a lot of VBA codes and tricks and none of them works if a formula is entered in C2. BUT if I type a value manually in C2 the date and time is updated as needed. This is of course because a real value is entered/changes - where the formula stays the same, so to speak.

**Question:**
Is it possible to create a VBA code (or something else) that updates D2 when the result of the formula in C2 changes?

If possible, I need this to be active for the cells C2:C30 (+ D2:D30 for the date+time)

Using Excel 2010.

Comment: "I have tried a lot of VBA codes" Care to show us [what you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could fill the dependend cell (D2) by a User Defined Function (VBA Macro Function) that takes the value of the C2-Cell as input parameter, returning the current date as ouput.

Having C2 as input parameter for the UDF in D2 tells Excel that it needs to reevaluate D2 everytime C2 changes (that is if auto-calculation of formulas is turned on for the workbook).

**EDIT:**

Here is some code:

For the UDF:

```
    Public Function UDF_Date(ByVal data) As Date

        UDF_Date = Now()

    End Function
```

As Formula in D2:

```
=UDF_Date(C2)
```

You will have to give the D2-Cell a Date-Time Format, or it will show a numeric representation of the date-value.

And you can expand the formula over the desired range by draging it if you keep the C2 reference in the D2-formula relative.

**Note:**
This still might not be the ideal solution because every time Excel recalculates the workbook the date in D2 will be reset to the current value.
To make D2 only reflect the last time C2 was changed there would have to be some kind of tracking of the past value(s) of C2.
This could for example be implemented in the UDF by providing also the address alonside the value of the input parameter, storing the input parameters in a hidden sheet, and comparing them with the previous values everytime the UDF gets called.

**Addendum:**

Here is a sample implementation of an UDF that tracks the changes of the cell values and returns the date-time when the last changes was detected.
When using it, please be aware that:

- The usage of the UDF is the same as described above.
- The UDF works only for single cell input ranges.
- The cell values are tracked by storing the last value of cell and the
  date-time when the change was detected in the document properties of the
  workbook. If the formula is used over large datasets the size of the
  file might increase considerably as for every cell that is tracked by
  the formula the storage requirements increase (last value of cell +
  date of last change.) Also, maybe Excel is not capable of handling
  very large amounts of document properties and the code might brake at
  a certain point.
- If the name of a worksheet is changed all the tracking information of the therein contained cells is lost.
- The code might brake for cell-values for which conversion to string is non-deterministic.
- The code below is **not tested** and should be regarded only as proof of
  concept. **Use it at your own risk**.

  ```
  Public Function UDF_Date(ByVal inData As Range) As Date

      Dim wb As Workbook
      Dim dProps As DocumentProperties
      Dim pValue As DocumentProperty
      Dim pDate As DocumentProperty
      Dim sName As String
      Dim sNameDate As String

      Dim bDate As Boolean
      Dim bValue As Boolean
      Dim bChanged As Boolean

      bDate = True
      bValue = True

      bChanged = False


      Dim sVal As String
      Dim dDate As Date

      sName = inData.Address & "_" & inData.Worksheet.Name
      sNameDate = sName & "_dat"

      sVal = CStr(inData.Value)
      dDate = Now()

      Set wb = inData.Worksheet.Parent

      Set dProps = wb.CustomDocumentProperties

  On Error Resume Next

      Set pValue = dProps.Item(sName)

      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
          bValue = False
          Err.Clear
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

      If Not bValue Then
          bChanged = True
          Set pValue = dProps.Add(sName, False, msoPropertyTypeString, sVal)
      Else
          bChanged = pValue.Value <> sVal
          If bChanged Then
              pValue.Value = sVal
          End If
      End If

  On Error Resume Next

      Set pDate = dProps.Item(sNameDate)

      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
          bDate = False
          Err.Clear
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

      If Not bDate Then
          Set pDate = dProps.Add(sNameDate, False, msoPropertyTypeDate, dDate)
      End If

      If bChanged Then
          pDate.Value = dDate
      Else
          dDate = pDate.Value
      End If


      UDF_Date = dDate
   End Function
  ```

Comment: +1 this is a good way to do it, you cant really use a formula as all the time related functions are volatile and recalculate at the drop of a hat

Comment: Hi and thank you for the quick answer. I tried what you posted but get a #NAME? even if the cell has been formatted to show a date.

Comment: #Name? probably means that Excel does not find the UDF. Where have you stored the VBA function, is it declared Public, and does the name correspond to what you have written in D2?

Comment: @ Roman: This could get a bit difficult. In real life the value in C2:C30 is from other workbooks (excel files). Fx: ='[workfile1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$W$32

Comment: @ Roman: I stored the VBA function by hitting Alt+F11 and pasted it there - and added the =UDF_Date(C2) in D2.

Comment: Well, it is the question where you have pasted it... possibly in the immediate window, there it can not work.
Create a new module (right-click on the workbook symbol in the left-hand tree-view in the vba-editor, and chose insert... module), then insert the function into the module and save the workbook. Now it could work.

Comment: HOLY MEAT ON A STICK! IT WORKS!! Thank you Thank you Thank you Thank you so so SO much for ending 3 days of hair pulling nightmare!!! This works like a charm!! +1 !

Comment: Glad that it works for you... but please keep in mind also what I wrote in the note in the post..

Comment: You are absolutely right. Fix one problem and another show it's face :( How to implement into UDF?

Comment: @ Roman: Regarding what you wrote in the "Note" area - I'm not sure how to do this. The date/time updates every time I open the workbook. Should only do this when value is updated ...

Comment: @Roman: **You are an excel god!** This seems to work perfectly and just as I want it to. Thank you so much for your effort! The date/time gets updated when changes to other workbooks are made. I will keep a backup workbook just in case something unforeseen should happen to the main workbook _(better to be safe)_ ;) .. Thanks again! (I will let you know if I have any weird problems - so you know if the code is/gets unstable). +100 ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Make the insertion of the date conditional upon the range.

This has an advantage of not changing the dates unless the content of the cell is changed, and it is in the range C2:C2, even if the sheet is closed and saved, it doesn't recalculate unless the adjacent cell changes.

Adapted from [this tip](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Determine_if_a_cell_is_within_a_range_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/484.html) and @Paul S answer

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim R1 As Range
 Dim R2 As Range
 Dim InRange As Boolean
    Set R1 = Range(Target.Address)
    Set R2 = Range("C2:C20")
    Set InterSectRange = Application.Intersect(R1, R2)

  InRange = Not InterSectRange Is Nothing
     Set InterSectRange = Nothing
   If InRange = True Then
     R1.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
   End If
     Set R1 = Nothing
     Set R2 = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Comment: This seems very elegant. Will try it out. Thanks! ;o)

Comment: This only work if you manually change the data within the range (and it's perfect for that). But if you have a formula in the cell (as I do) it will not update/change the date when changes are made. Ergo, I can't use it. Sorry.

Comment: Your question said "Whenever C2 changes value (actual value, not formula)" so I thought that meant you were actually changing the value, perhaps that is not clear

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$C$2" Then

        ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value = Now()

    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add `=IF(B3="","Not Allocated",Now())` and change the format of the column to the required date and time format. But here if the B column is edited, the date and time of the respective column that needs the update will gets updated automatically for all the columns since not checking the old value. But if it is fine to get current Time this can be easily used.