# Update date when related cell in same row is changed

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

Refering to this link :
[Automatic date update in a cell when another cell's value changes (as calculated by a formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311973/automatic-date-update-in-a-cell-when-another-cells-value-changes-as-calculated)

Answer from ***Roman*** Is Helpful. but instead to store the oldvalue & oldDate to document properties, I'd prefer to store them in cell (table) within the same row.

here is what I try to change the function:

```
Public Function UDF_EditDate(ByVal newData As Range, ByRef oldData As Range, ByRef   oldDate As Range) As Date
If newData.Count = 1 And oldData.Count = 1 And oldDate.Count = 1 Then

    If (oldDate.Value = "") Or (newData.Value <> oldData.Value) Then
        oldData.Value = newData.Value
        Range(oldDate).Value = Now()
    End If

    UDF_EditDate = Now()
End If
End Function
```

and in the formula cell let say "D1" I put:

```
= UDF_EditDate(A1,B1,C1)
```

But, Unfortunately, this function doesn't work as expected.

any one could help me review and solve my problem?

Comment: `oldData.Value = newData.Value` You cannot change any other cell's data using a UDF (There are exceptions to this rule though). You can only change the current cell's value.

Comment: I don't want to bulk the document properties value. Instead, I'll use cells to store it in. 
then, Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below watches column A on a sheet, and when it is changed puts current date to the same row column B:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Target.Next.Value = Date
End Sub
```

This will work correctly only if single cell is changed, try to modify it for multiple yourself

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [avb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3468925/avb)

I did slight modification for extended number of column A to D and put the update on Column E for the corresponded row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("A:D")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each x In Target
        Cells(x.Row, 5).Value = Now
    Next
End Sub
```