# Vba function or formula to extract last edit timestamp from a cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

There is a file with 100's of hyperlinked cell in excel, which the link gets updated on a weekly bases from multiple individuals. I was wondering if there is a formula or vba scripts to get the date and time of the update to the hyperlinked cells instead of entering the date and time manually.

Please keep in mind that the hyperlinks are not in dates, it is just headers of workbooks

Comment: The timestamp for when the cell containing the hyperlink was last edited?

Comment: yes, the last update of the link.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible to extract the timestamp of the last update of the hyperlinked but though ask the experts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic date update in a cell when another cell's value changes (as calculated by a formula)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311973/automatic-date-update-in-a-cell-when-another-cells-value-changes-as-calculated)

Comment: The top answer in the link above leads to the solution you're looking for

Comment: can you give an example? not sure how it will work for the hyerlinked cell.

Comment: Please follow the link and read the answer.  Its detailed with example and code

Comment: Thanks for the link. It does help but is there a way to extract the time stamp of an existing hyperlinked cell?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a last edited property that exists for cells.  There is one for the workbook itself but to my knowledge you cannot find out when it was last edited. Have to actually track it with the above listed method.

Comment: Ah ok thanks for your help. Kind of new to vba i tried utilizing the code in the link but when running code the marco box comes up asking me to create a Marco first. I run my Marco with sub() at beginning but how do i run the Marcos in the link?

Comment: i tried using call function as well but no luck

Comment: Don't mean to sound harsh but the top answer tells you what to do step by step in an example.  Even with explicit example cells (C2 and D2) to see what is happening.  Please read it again thoroughly.  It even includes the situations that the formula would fail etc.

Comment: @ashareef I don't think you understand exactly what the OP is after. Am I right in saying you want the actual date stamp from the file in which the hyperlink is pointing at? For example, if C:\Test.doc was edited at 19:03, you'd see 19:03 in a cell?

Comment: Oh hopefully then what you posted helps him.  I completely will have misunderstood.  Cell vs file would be two different things altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code in a module and call the routine using `Call UpdateTimeStamp`

```
Sub UpdateTimeStamp()
  Dim HL As Hyperlink
       For Each HL In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
         HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value = HL.Address
         HL.Range.offset(0, 1).value = FileDateTime(HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).value)
       Next
End Sub
```

this should return the last time the file at the end of the hyperlink was updated in the cell to the right of the hyperlink. **However I have not had time to test this!**

**Update**

```
Sub UpdateTimeStamp()
    Dim HL As Hyperlink
    For Each HL In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
      HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value = FileDateTime(HL.Address)
    Next
End Sub
```

This code works fine for me, returning the date and time the file at the end of link was modified

Comment: when running the marco, i get a path not found error. I check the path of the hyperlink and it does work not sure as to why it is giving me that error.

Comment: HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value = FileDateTime(HL.Range.Offset(0, 1).Value) this is the code that is highlighted.

Comment: I'll have a look today, I was out yesterday and havent been back to check anything

Comment: That’s interesting. So for the file which has over 100 hyperlinks, when running the Marco i get the error of path not found but when opening a new workbook and hyperlinking a cell to a path the code works. Curious as to why it doesn’t work for the file that has multitude of hyperlink and work fine when opening a new workbook and hyperlink a cell to a path,  Any ideas?

Comment: @user3642399 do you know that all of your 100+ hyperlinks are actually found? Why dont you increment a variable such as `i` as part of the loop and set an error trap to show a message box with the value of `i`. This will tell you which hyperlink could not be found

Comment: some what got it to work but ran into some issue. 
so, when the marco runs it goes in debugging phase and highlights the timestamp code but when i do save as and saved the workbook and then run the marco. it works fine. Though that was very weird, any input?

Comment: @user3642399 - Do you have automatic update of links switched on? I'm not sure of the environment in which your workbook is set up, but if your hyperlinks are pointing to networked locations, this may be causing an issue with being unable to find paths

Comment: your question "Do you have automatic update of links switched on?" sorry but how would i know if the link is swithed on to auto. and yes the hyperlink is pointing to a network location.

Comment: the auto switch if off