# Automatic date update in a cell when another cell's value changes (as calculated by a formula) (CONTINUED)

Tags: excel, datetime, vba

So I wanted to just add this question to the existing [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311973/automatic-date-update-in-a-cell-when-another-cells-value-changes-as-calculated), but you need a 50 rating so I had to start a new one. I apologize.

someone posted this code which works great however, the field I want to populate with the date and time is on another sheet.  I'm wondering if someone could tell me what to change to identify the sheet that needs to be changed. The cell offset is also off because the field that would be updated on sheetA needs the Now() in the same cell on sheetB.

Here is the code from the previous post:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Dim R1 As Range
 Dim R2 As Range
 Dim InRange As Boolean
    Set R1 = Range(Target.Address)
    Set R2 = Range("C2:C20")
    Set InterSectRange = Application.Intersect(R1, R2)

  InRange = Not InterSectRange Is Nothing
     Set InterSectRange = Nothing
   If InRange = True Then
     R1.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()
   End If
     Set R1 = Nothing
     Set R2 = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to link to the previous post.  While you're doing that, please pick better tags.  Is this vba?  vb?  excel?  c#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311973/automatic-date-update-in-a-cell-when-another-cells-value-changes-as-calculated

Comment: `So I wanted to just add this question to the existing question but you need a 50 rating` - editing your questions into other people's questions might eventually get you banned.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Sheet2` is your `SheetB`. You just need to change one line.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim R1 As Range
    Dim R2 As Range
    Dim InRange As Boolean
    Set R1 = Range(Target.Address)
    Set R2 = Range("C2:C20")
    Set InterSectRange = Application.Intersect(R1, R2)

    InRange = Not InterSectRange Is Nothing
    Set InterSectRange = Nothing
    If InRange = True Then
        'R1.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()  '<-- Commented
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 1).Value = Now()   '<-- Added
    End If
    Set R1 = Nothing
    Set R2 = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!!

Comment: If this answer helped you than can you pls [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so that other will know you have the answer now.

Comment: This actually did work... however... I tried to run the worksheet on a mobile device (which is what it needs to run on) and apparently you can't run VBA on the mobile version of Excel.  So, unless someone can point me to a version of Excel that runs on an Android device or on an iPad I actually need to accomplish the same thing as the code is doing without the code... Is that possible?